# How to enable LAN access to OpenVPN clients

Tags: networking, openvpn

I have a server with 2 real NIC and 1 virtual NIC (tun0) created by OpenVPN.

```
eth0 is LAN - IP 192.168.2.1
eth1 is Internet - IP is public internet IP
tun0 is created by openvpn
```

What I need is that clients that connect to VPN server over eth1 will also get access to eth0 network, eg. will be able to connect to 192.168.2.21

This used to work in past until I rebooted the server and routing info got reset :/ I configured this couple years ago and forgot how I did that.

Routing table now looks like this:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         public gw       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
public ip       *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.2.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.8.0     192.168.8.2     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.8.2     *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
```

When I launch OpenVPN it tries to add route

```
Tue Oct 11 19:29:58 2016 /sbin/ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 via 192.168.8.2
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Tue Oct 11 19:29:58 2016 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
```

It however doesn't seem to be possible because it already exists. When I remove this route openVPN succeeds in adding but it's no longer possible for server to reach 192.168.2.0/24 network.

How can I make it work?

EDIT: yes, I have both IPv4 and IPv6 forwarding enabled

Comment: Your question isn’t entirely clear on what happens where: VPN server or client. Please clarify. Also, for this to work, all machines on the `192.168.2.0/24` network need to know that `192.168.8.0/24` (the VPN subnet, I assume) is reachable via `192.168.2.1`. If `192.168.2.1` is not the default gateway, you should set up a route on the default gateway.

Comment: @DanielB this what I describe here is server, which is also a gateway itself, it's DNS, DHCP and router for LAN and it also hosts that 192.168.8.0 subnet for VPN. This all used to work until I rebooted it, so there is no problem on client side. VPN client already pushes route to client, the problem is that the VPN server doesn't seem to allow machines from 192.168.8.0 to access 192.168.2.0 network

Comment: You misunderstand: A route needs to exist both ways for packets to go through both ways. You can easily verify whether packets are received using Wireshark. // Also, you automatically get a route to the subnet of an adapter’s IP address. Always.

Answer (score 0):

you'll need ip_forward set in the sysctl, and an accept line in the FORWARD table in iptables (which often defaults to ACCEPT anyhow)

http://www.ducea.com/2006/08/01/how-to-enable-ip-forwarding-in-linux/

Comment: I already have that, that isn't the issue here.

Comment: yeah, you'll also need the masquerade line from that link.

Comment: `MASQUERADE` is only needed when a fully routed setup is not possible. It is possible, so it shouldn’t be used.

Answer (score 0):

First, the necessary routes:

- VPN clients need a route to `192.168.2.0/24`, via your VPN gateway (presumably at `192.168.8.1` inside the virtual network)
- Devices in `192.168.2.0/24` need a route to `192.168.8.0/24` – because it appears your VPN server resides on the default gateway, additional configuration is not required.

Then, the configuration. The specifics depend on the topology (net30/p2p or subnet), but it’s like this in general:

```
topology net30    
server 192.168.8.0 255.255.255.0

push "route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0"
```

I omitted all irrelevant (but nonetheless mandatory) options here. Do note however that the `route` is only pushed to clients. **It must not be set on the server**.

Since the client receives all necessary settings via push, no special configuration is needed.

Comment: `topology net30` is depreciated, use `topology subnet`